# Why do I get this Fedena installation error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, fedena

I wanted to install Fedena on CPanel, but when I used the command `rake gems:unpack` I got this error:

```
Fedena requires i18n gem version 0.4.0 to be installed.
Run gem install i18n -v 0.4.0
rake aborted!
ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead.
/home/iiumprin/public_html/projectfedena-fedena-84b5ad9/Rakefile:8
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have the i18n gem inside my Ruby but it's still giving me this error, what should I do?

'rake gems:unpack --trace'

```
iiumprin@iiumprinting.com [~/public_html/projectfedena-fedena-84b5ad9]# rake gems:unpack --trace
Fedena requires i18n gem version 0.4.0 to be installed.Run gem install i18n -v 0.4.0
rake aborted!
ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead.
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb:2
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
/home/iiumprin/public_html/projectfedena-fedena-84b5ad9/Rakefile:8
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:637:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33
/usr/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:23
```

Comment: Please format your question, it's impossible to read it now!

Comment: @Michael Szyndel Sorry edited the question already...

Comment: It sounds like your Ruby is old, but we can't tell because you didn't give us information to help you. The error says "`See full trace by running task with --trace`". Run with that flag, and add the pertinent parts, and add the output of `gem env`. See http://sscce.org/ for how to provide the needed information.

Comment: @the Tin Man updated.

Comment: I don't see the output of `gem env`, but it's easy to see you're running Linux and have an old version of Ruby. If you have RVM or rbenv installed, I'd recommend using one of them to load a current version; At a minimum you should be using 1.9.3-p448. If you don't have [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install), you should seriously consider using them to allow you to manage and maintain current versions of Ruby more easily. If you opt for RVM, read ALL all the installation instructions. At least upgrade Ruby no matter what.